# Unable to get the Sumif property of the worksheetfunction Class

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone explain what I could do to fix this?

[image]

Here's the current code:

```
SumFinalUnusedSPQCement = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("V4:V" & lastRow + 3), ">0", "B4:B" & lastRow + 3))
SumFinalUnusedSPQSand = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("W4:W" & lastRow + 3), ">0", "C4:C" & lastRow + 3))
SumFinalUnusedSPQAggregate = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("X4:X" & lastRow + 3), ">0", "D4:D" & lastRow + 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `Range` before `B4:B` and similarly for the others. It should be

```
SumFinalUnusedSPQCement = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf( _
                                      Range("V4:V" & lastRow + 3), _
                                      ">0", _
                                      Range("B4:B" & lastRow + 3) _
                                      )
```

Also you do not need `WorksheetFunction.Sum`.